# Cast column to dynamic size based on function argument

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to cast something to char(n) where n is a function argument

```
ALTER FUNCTION FixMe(@colName varchar, @width integer) RETURNS varchar
AS BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(@colName as char(@width))
END
```

This code is giving an error of

> `Incorrect syntax near '@width'.`

I have also tried executing this with `EXEC()` via:

```
EXEC('set @retval = CAST(@colName as char(' + @width + '))')
```

But I then run in to

> `Invalid use of side-effecting or
>   time-dependent operator in 'EXECUTE
>   STRING' within a function.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you did manage to get this to work in a function your `RETURNS varchar` statement would cause the result to be implicitly converted to `varchar(1)` on the way out.

I assume this is related to your previous question in which case this might work better for you.

```
ALTER FUNCTION FixMe(@colvalue VARCHAR(8000),
                     @width    INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN REPLACE(RTRIM(@colvalue), ' ', '&nbsp;') + 
               CASE
                   WHEN @width > LEN(@colvalue) 
                   THEN REPLICATE('&nbsp;', @width - LEN(@colvalue))
                   ELSE ''
               END        
  END
```

Comment: But I need to return value in grid as number not string